# Android emulator is crashing frequently

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb

After getting the latest update for **Honeycomb** , it seems the Android emulator is crashing and not responding quite frequently.

Also observed starting emulator with AVD which has snapshot stored earlier is also causing emulator freezing .

Any workaround ?

Comment: I'm getting this as well.  If I look at DDMS, I am getting out of memory errors.  Is this similar to errors that you're getting?

Comment: Did you try creating a new AVD Device from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

To reboot your emulator when it freezes, try running a cold boot. You can do this by navigating to the emulator files on your OS. If you are using Windows OS, this terminal command would look something like this:

```
cd C:\Users\your-account\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
```

Once you have navigated to the emulator directory, you can force a cold boot by running the following command:

```
.\emulator.exe -avd Your_Device_Name -no-snapshot-load
```

This will reboot your emulator.